# Напишите программу, которая найдёт произведение пар чисел списка. Парой считаем первый и последний элемент, второй и предпоследний и т.д

Tags: python, list

Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу решить задачу, так как только учусь...
Напишите программу, которая найдёт произведение пар чисел списка. Парой считаем первый и последний элемент, второй и предпоследний и т.д.
результат должен быть таким: Пример: - [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] => [12, 15, 16]; (то есть 2 * 6 = 12, 3 * 5 = 15, 4 которая осталась лишней возводится в собственную степень 4 * 4 = 16)

я попробовал написать такой код:

```
x = input().split() 
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = int(x[i])
    count = x[0:2]
    count1 = x[2:]
    result = map(sum, (count, count1))

print(list(result))
```

я понимаю что данный код у меня складывает значения... Помогите пожалуйста. Если будет возможность дать развернутый ответ, что бы объяснить на пальцах как будет выглядеть правильное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не изобретайте, раз только изучаете - решайте в лоб

у вас не код, а мешанина каких-то команд, все свалили в кучу в надежде, что все заработает?

напишите код на бумажке словами и потом превращайте его в питон

1. запросить у пользователя строку с числами
2. разбить строку на отдельные слова (числа)
3. перевести разбитые слова в числа
4. пройтись в цикле от `0` до `length / 2 + 1` (до половины массива)
5. умножить числа одинаково удаленных от начала и конца списка между собой `arr[i] * arr[len(arr) - i - 1]`
6. занести полученный результат в массив
7. вывести массив на экран

**P.S.**

задача решается в 1 строку, но вам надо использовать 10-15 строчек пока вы учите базу

И НЕ МЕШАЙТЕ ВСЁ В КУЧУ - УЖАС!!!

ошибки в вашем коде (кроме всего прочего)

```
x = input().split() # получен список строк, а не чисел
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = int(x[i]) # запись числа идет последовательно слово за словом
    count = x[0:2] # а результаты используются уже сразу по всему списку - но там до сих пор слова, а не числа
    count1 = x[2:] # это список, а не число
    result = map(sum, (count, count1)) # результат - число и никуда не записывается

print(list(result)) # тут будет последний результат превращен в список, содержащий 1 число
```